# Fit to Printer Margins vs Reduce to Printer Margins

Tags: printing

I'm using Foxit PhantomPDF 8.2.0.

1. How do they differ?
2. For [this PDF](http://www.mediafire.com/file/3rwltppeobn9z1s/p._320_-_JC_Smith%2527s_The_Law_of_Contract_%25282018_2_ed%2529_-_Davies.pdf/file), why don't they yield the same result? See beneath please.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post on the Foxit forum](http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-phantompdf/24255-page-size):

> **Fit To Printer Margins:** Scales small pages up and large pages down to fit the paper.
>   **Reduce To Printer Margins:** Resizes only large pages to fit the paper and prints small pages as they are.

The images look slightly different on the preview, but print them both ways to see if and how the actual print output differs.

Unless someone is intimately familiar with Foxit's algorithms, it may take a little speculation to explain what you're seeing.

I'm assuming that the 95.65% zoom shown in the screenshots means that a small amount of shrinkage was used for both methods. That would rule out Reduce to Fit being actual size and Fit to Margins being enlarged.

I suspect that Foxit may be working with the page content rather than just the size of the paper page.  So the resized text may end up closer or farther from the paper's edge depending on how much margin is available.  It could also be that the two fitting algorithms are slightly different, so the results are slightly different.

The document and paper sizes match.  It's possible that the Reduce to Fit algorithm sees that the text will fit inside the printer margin, while the Fit to Margin algorithm is working with the document paper size and allows some extra margin.

It could be that this is just a quirk that Foxit hasn't ironed out yet.  You could always run some tests with documents that are larger and smaller than the output size by varying degrees and with different document margins to nail down what Foxit is doing.

However, to the task of printing your document, how important is it that the margin be a precise, designated value?  If the actual print margins differ and are consistent with the images, you can just pick the one you prefer.  The other option would be to use the next print setting, Custom scale, and experiment, starting at 95.65%.  That algorithm may produce still a third margin size, but you will have direct control to make it precisely what you want.